# Random clock Generation with unequal 1s and 0s distribution?

Tags: fpga, integrated-circuit, clock, cmos, vlsi

We need a pseudo-random clock with a length `N`, in such a way that out of every `N` clock pulses, `M` of them should randomly made zero (`M<<N`). What we want to do is to sample a signal in a random fashion. Meaning that, out of every `N` sample points (from Nyquist grid) we need to take `M` samples. Then through some processing and assumptions about signal structure, other un-sampled (`N-M` samples) points are recovered. 
Now I am using Linear Shift Registers, something like below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvKxkx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It works good, however, I do not want equal distribution for 1s and 0s, I mean I want something like 20% of clock cycles to be 1 and 80% to be zero. 
To achieve that, I made to `AND` output of two circuits like above to change probability from 50% for both 1s and zeros to 25% for 1s and 75% for zeros (in figure below, with different seeds).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQnBXB.png)</sup>

It is good at the cost of doubling the power and chip area:( . I am seeking a way to make the system work with only 1 random clock generator circuit, not two.

- Is possible through implanting some special initial seed change probability distribution of 1s and 0s in output sequence ?
- Is there any power-area efficient method to accomplish this?

I was thinking to store a random binary sequence (with length of `N`) in a ROM and then `And` its output  with the clock to make a random clock.

Comment: Depends how random it needs to be. If storing a sequence in a ROM is not an issue, then you could also use an LFSR to make a pseudo-random sequence. A bit more info on the application would help.

Comment: I second the lfsr.  look for "irreducible polynomial" and pick which one gives the variations you want

Comment: The clock frequency is up to 1Mhz

Comment: explain "M of them should randomly made zero "   random edge, what min max time range and coherent with 1MHz?  Random phase?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply take all of the samples at the full clock rate and then randomly discard some of them?

Comment: @Dave Tweed, good idea, but we've already done that to demonstrate the system works in general, but as real world system, this system should be efficient, so minimum number of samples must be acquired.

Comment: I've found the answer, as @Tom Carpenter and @b degnan mentioned using LFSR, so I modify the question to be more specific.

Comment: I can't really understand why this has to be efficient. It sounds like you're doing an experiment, and your speed is very low. Are you sure you're not doing premature micro-optimizations here?

Comment: @pipe , because it is going to be part of an low power ADC, and if it does consume a huge power the ADC will no longer would be called low power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the contents of the N-bit LFSR as an N-bit integer. This number will have a uniform distribution of values from 1 to 2<sup>N</sup> - 1. You can generate a variable density of mask bits by comparing this number to a threshold that you also vary from 1 to 2<sup>N</sup> - 1. The output of this comparator is the clock mask you seek.

Comment: This method is flexible in changing distribution, so when I want like 17% of 1s, I'll set the threshold to 0.17*(2^N-1). I'll check to figure out if it is area and power efficient too.

Comment: The answer is great and provides flexible distribution, however it stills requires an Comparator. I am researching to find out if I only use a few bits of N bit random generator and compare it to a threshold can acviehve good performance.

Comment: Yes, of course. Any subset of M bits from the N-bit LFSR will contain a uniform distribution of values from 0 to 2^M - 1. So if you only need one part in 2^M resolution in your threshold settings, you can just use an M-bit comparator.