# How to build a noise generator based entirely on logic gates?

Tags: digital-logic, noise, generator, ttl

I would like to build a noise generator based on logic gates. It could be white noise generator or a random bits generator that sound similar to a noise source. I need a circuit recommendation or an idea how to make it.

Updated: The purpose is to make an electronic music device. Any kind of noise can be interesting for me.

Comment: The question that inevitably comes to my mind is: why? what problem is this going to solve?

Comment: Noise is not logical.

Comment: It's funny that you're happy with either white noise or binary generator, since those two would have drastically different properties. It sounds like you don't know what you need.

Comment: An similar answer is already given here : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252311/random-clock-generation-with-unequal-1s-and-0s-distribution

Comment: The purpose is to make an electronic music device. Any kind of noise can be interesting for me. Thanks.

Comment: I am quite sure there is some specialized diodes for generating noise. You won't get random noise from numeric since you will always get the harmonics of the clock.

Comment: "Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin" -- John von Neumann. But I suppose with music, the more sinful the better.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Shift register noise is both binary and white

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes you are right;)

Answer (score 6):

How about one of these: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/LFSR.html).

It is described as a white noise source: -

> 24 Stage Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR)
>
> This circuit can be used to generate a pseudo-random sequence of 0's
>   and 1's -- that is "white noise" or "static." The schematic shows a 24
>   stage shift register with XNOR taps at registers 7, 16, 22, and 24
>   using the Fibonacci configuration. With these taps, the circuit
>   generates a "maximal length sequence" of pseudo random values which
>   repeats only after (2\$^{24}\$ - 1) clock pulses.

Or maybe just use an analogue one based on the emitter-base breakdown voltage of transistor Q1: -

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest method for generating "noise" with digital logic is to generate a pseudorandom binary sequence (PRBS) with a linear feedback shift register (LFSR).  The output of a PRBS generator, especially for the longer sequences (PRBS31), can have a very wide bandwidth.  It's also a pretty simple circuit to build; just shift registers and XOR gates.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_binary_sequence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register .

Comment: I can tell you from experience, having built such noise generators, that a single LFSR sounds 'lumpy'. Although it meets a large number of tests for randomness, it does have more structure than does white noise, to the human ear. Building at least 3 of different lengths, and XORing their outputs  together, sounds much more consistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will definitely try this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a digital white noise generator with a small 8-bit 8-pin micro such as a PIC12F series. It's basically a code implementation of a PRNG based on one or more shift-registers, very easy to do.

Since you are interested in audio you might actually want pink noise. There are samples available on-line if you want to compare- white noise sounds much harsher. You can get that from white noise via an analog filter that approximates 3dB/octave or you can use a **much** more powerful micro and implement a digital filter.

[Here](http://m.eet.com/media/1136188/80703di.pdf) is a somewhat more sophisticated circuit than the minimum that can produce Gaussian noise and pink noise.

Comment: I will try this approach definitely. Is there any code programming needed? Or this micro PIC12F is just ready? Thanks.

Comment: There are examples on the net, including the one I linked, which provide assembly code. You need an assembler program (available from Microchip for free) if a hex binary file is not provided and a chip programmer. The latter costs < $15 for a clone from China with a ZIF socket or $35 (?) in the official version which does not have the ZIF so you have to use a solderless breadboard or whatever.